Why there is no any output after prisma query ? Where does it stuck?
Below are my some package details.
"prisma": "2.30.3",
"@prisma/client": "2.30.3",

I am using docker-compose up to run postgres db.
Below is my prisma schema
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  log = ["query", "info", "warn", "error"]
}

Here is my client connection
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ["query","info","error","warn"]
})

This is a simple query that I am trying. (I also tried SELECT 1 but it did not work too)
const data = await prisma.user.count();
console.log(data,"========= data");

Below are the logs from prisma during execution. There is no any log or console output after prisma:query
prisma:info Started http server on http://127.0.0.1:61370
  prisma:engine Search for Query Engine in /Users/yash/Documents/Projects/my_project/node_modules/.prisma/client +1ms
  prisma:engine stdout Fetched a connection from the pool +9ms
  prisma:engine Client Version: 2.30.3 +1ms
  prisma:engine Engine Version: query-engine b8c35d44de987a9691890b3ddf3e2e7effb9bf20 +0ms
  prisma:engine Active provider: postgresql +0ms
  prisma:engine stdout Unknown error +17ms
prisma:query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT "public"."User"."id" FROM "public"."User" WHERE 1=1 OFFSET $1) AS "sub"


docker-compose logs postgres is clean. there are no errors.
LOG_QUERY=info, LOG_LEVEL=debug, DEBUG="prisma:*" is configured in .env
node version is 20.17. I tried 18 too but it gives connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:50111 error which is not there in version 20.17

I tried some of the ways but nothing is working. There is not enough budget to migrate app to latest versions of packages at this moment. We had to do this because node is upgraded on server. previous prisma versions were 2.18.
